# Не заменяются значения при вертске html

Tags: html, вёрстка, display

Я оптимизирую сайт под мобильные устройства, и я сделал так что при конкретной ширине display из значения block, должен становиться none, но посмотрев код элемента, я увидел что новое значение не заменяет старое, оно просто почему то перечеркнуто, но если я вручную уберу старое значение, то новое встанет на его место, что делать? Заранее всем спасибо))[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты должен делать media запрос при определенном разрешении, советую прочитай про них

Comment: А можно посмотреть код сайта?

Comment: Всем спасибо, но решение было гораздо легче, надо просто было добавить !important, кому интересно то вот ссылка http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie

Comment: Очень плохой стиль совать !important где надо и не надо. Лучше стараться избегать этого всеми силами. Вам уже написали, читайте и используйте медиа-запросы для разных разрешений.